# Find a specific path with "find" dynamically

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to find a specific file/folder based on directory name . There are one thing i could not understand which is tabcmd -> ../bin.2012....

When i did a ls -lrt on a specific path. for e.g

```
cmd : ls -lrt /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/customer-bin.20212.21.1217.2251

it will list as 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 33 Dec 23 07:56 atrdiag -> ../bin.20212.21.1217.2251/atrdiag
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 32 Dec 23 07:56 tabcmd -> ../bin.20212.21.1217.2251/tabcmd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 39 Dec 23 07:56 serveractutil -> ../bin.20212.21.1217.2251/serveractutil
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 34 Dec 23 07:56 odbcinst -> ../bin.20212.21.1217.2251/odbcinst
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 31 Dec 23 07:56 iusql -> ../bin.20212.21.1217.2251/iusql
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 30 Dec 23 07:56 isql -> ../bin.20212.21.1217.2251/isql
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 37 Dec 23 07:56 custactutil -> ../bin.20212.21.1217.2251/custactutil
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 29 Dec 23 07:56 tsm -> ../bin.20212.21.1217.2251/tsm
```

The objective is to find tabcmd path dynamically as this path will change from time to time.  "I could not use whereis command as it is not registered as a system path/variable"

Alternatively, what i did was

```
TEST=`find /opt/tableau -type d -name "tabcmd"`
echo "Tabcmd path is : $TEST"
```

However with the cmd i tried ,, it is returning empty
it returned  `"Tabcmd path is : "`

Update :
when i tried using command below

```
TABCMD_PATH=`find /opt/tableau/tableau_server -name "tabcmd"`
echo $TABCMD_PATH 

/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/bin.20212.21.1217.2251/tabcmd /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/customer-bin.20212.21.1217.2251/tabcmd
```

this it will print 2 times instead of 1 and if this is the approach i should take ?

Answer (score 0):

It is empty because you are finding for a directory called *tabcmd*, you have to find by file `-type f`

```
TEST=`find /opt/tableau -type d -name "tabcmd"`
echo "Tabcmd path is : $TEST"
```

And the following print two path because the file is in both paths, the file link and the symbolic link:

```
TABCMD_PATH=`find /opt/tableau/tableau_server -name "tabcmd"`
echo $TABCMD_PATH 

/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/bin.20212.21.1217.2251/tabcmd /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/customer-bin.20212.21.1217.2251/tabcmd
```

You have to find the file excluding the symbolic link:

```
TABCMD_PATH=`find /opt/tableau/tableau_server -type f -name "tabcmd"`
echo $TABCMD_PATH
```